# search bar filter using Vue js

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to filter a table that get data from api and I tried this solution but it doesnt work.
I couldnt find where the problem is and if I pass the search input event listener

and here is my table component :

```
<template>
<table class="mt-12 border-2 border-gray-600">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th v-for="header in data.headers" :key="header" class="text-left border-l-2 border-gray-600 border-b-2 border-gray-600 bg-red-400 ">{{ header }}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(rows, index) in data.rows" :key="index">
      <td v-for="row in rows" :key="row" class="border-l-2 border-gray-600"  >{{ row }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    data: Object,
    default: {}
  }
}
</script>
<style src="../assets/tailwind.css"/>
```

My question:

If anyone can help me to define my problem and solve this ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: can you create a stackblitz

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-yalow-sczxu?file=/src/App.vue:1285-1289

Comment: i create this one sandbox

Comment: why not listen to output property as event from search component ? You are emitting it but directly using it from computed ?

Comment: how do you mean

Comment: could you show me how in sandbox or stackblitz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your data as computed where you pass it as a prop.

```
 <BaseTable :data='data' />
```

Here instead of using like this create a computed which can be filteredData.

```
<BaseTable :data='filteredData' />
```

and in your props you can simply filter it or just send the data as it is.

```js
computed: {
     filteredData() {
          if(this.search) {
               // filter your data as you want and return
            }
           else // return your main data
      }
}
```

Here is a working simple example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/filterlist-example-vdwhg?file=/src/App.vue

And change your include to includes.

Comment: thank you so much ,but do i nedd add something to searchInput component?

Comment: Oh I shouldnt answer questions when I am sleepy :D filteredrows is your method. I will edit

Comment: i did what you said and the table disappear and when i write something in search input it doesnt show anything

Comment: OmerS no problem i am new to vue js and i am trying to learn  but i stuck here

Comment: Okay okay i will edit. I found my mistake.

Comment: Okay, you actually don't need to use a search component. If you don't use try what I said. I deleted my edit because it was wrong. If you want to use a search component you are just going to tell your parent what is the search input. If this solution doesnt work let me know so I can create a sandbox and show it to you

Comment: yes please if its possible to show me how to do it

Comment: do i need to write my function in computed?

Comment: I added sandbox. Simple example

Comment: thanks , did you tried if it works becuse it doesnt return any think

Comment: i added all same as you said but it doesnt return any output

Comment: try now. input is where you type something and it filters as if it includes substring of search input

Comment: yes it works but what did you change in your code because i think i still have same problem

Comment: i will update now my code and you could have a look

Comment: can you delete data object in your data. We dont need that. Because now this.search is not defined. Or do this.data.search

Comment: item.toLowerCase is not a function i get this error

Comment: this.data.filter. this should be this.data.rows.filter i guess. I would suggest dont type data in your data return thing. It confuses everything.

Comment: when i delete a data object , my table disappear and i dont get it rander in the app

Comment: because u use data.rows. Fix them pls.

Comment: i am doing my code in a sandbox and you can take look on it

Comment: first of all please dont use "data" in your VUE data field. change that name. Secondly you got that error because you have numbers in rows. you can use .toString().toLowerCase()

Comment: i really appreciate your help and i still didnt solve it and i tried to change data and my table goes ,so i wish for you a nice weekend and you were very helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

what error you are getting ? I think you are using this.search inside filteredRows function which is not a vue instance property. it should be this.data.search. The search is used with V-model as well so you should declare it outside data (JSON object).

Comment: i dont get any error but it doesnt work and i used this.data.search also it didnt